# Optimal Path-finding technique in a non-standard maze

Tags: java, optimization, path-finding, maze

So, my problem is that I'm currently working on a path-finding technique in an open world with tiles of various sizes. The object needs to find an optimal path to a destination inside an infinite world (it generates on the fly), which is filled with tiles of various sizes (which are not located on a set grid - they can have any location and size - and neither have to be integers). (The object has access to the data of all the tiles via and ArrayList). Now some factors that make this problem more difficult:

- The objects itself has a size and cannot move through tiles. Therefore, it is possible for a path to exist that is too narrow for the object to move through.
- The target destination may itself be a moving object.
- It is possible for there to be dozens of such objects at the same time - so it is necessary for the algorithm to either be light on the system or for the path to be calculated in a few separate ticks of the program.

I tried implementing solutions for maze-solving techniques, but the main problem is the in most mazes, the tiles can only have very specific coordinates (such as whole numbers) and are always the same size.

I also tried rendering the scene as a giant conventional maze where tiles are actually pixels of tiles (so if i have a 20x40 tile it becomes a 20x40 block of 1x1 tiles), but ran into performance issues and the still didn't solve the issue with a path potentially being to narrow for the object to fit through.

EDIT:

Terribly sorry for my poor wording before, that happens when I'm trying to rush to a solution without fully understanding the question. So what I'm using the algorithm for at the moment is for NPC enemies to find their way to the player around obstacles. Here is an example of a scene:

[image: Sample scenerio]

The black circle with an arrow is the player, the black bush-like blobs are the NPC enemies. So this my my current algorithm I'm using for the enemy AI:

```
void move() { //part of the Enemy class, this function is called once each tick for every enemy
  PVector velocity = new PVector(speed*game.dt, 0); //speed is a pre-set float denoting the enemy's speed, game.dt is deltatim
  velocity.rotate(atan2(game.player.location.y-location.y, game.player.location.x-location.x)); //game.player.location is a PVector of the player's position, location is a PVector of this enemy's position

  boolean init_collision = getTileCollision(); //getTileCollision is a boolean of whether this enemy is colliding with any tile
  location.add(velocity);
  boolean collision = getTileCollision();
  if (!init_collision && collision) { //if the enemy happens to spawn inside a tile, let is move out of it before checking for collision
    location.sub(velocity);

    if (desired_heading != -1) { //desired heading is the angle, in radians, of which 90-degree angle the enemy wants to move in, by default set to -1 (see my descrition of this algorithm below)
      velocity = new PVector(speed*game.dt, 0);
      velocity.rotate(desired_heading);
      location.add(velocity);
      if (getTileCollision()) {
        location.sub(velocity);
        velocity = new PVector(speed*game.dt, 0);
        velocity.rotate(current_heading); //current heading the an angle, in radians, of which 90-degree angle the enemy is currently moving in. set to -1 by default but can not equal -1 if desired_heading is not -1
        location.add(velocity);
        if (getTileCollision()) {
          location.sub(velocity);
          desired_heading = -1;
          current_heading = -1;
        }
      } else {
        desired_heading = -1;
        current_heading = -1;
      }
    } else {
      float original_heading = velocity.heading();
      desired_heading = radians(round(degrees(velocity.heading())/90.0)*90.0); //round to the nearest 90 degrees
      velocity = new PVector(speed*game.dt, 0);
      velocity.rotate(desired_heading);
      location.add(velocity);
      if (getTileCollision()) {
        location.sub(velocity);
      }
      float turn = radians(90);
      while (true) { //if it cant move, try rotating 90 degrees and moving
        velocity.rotate(turn);
        location.add(velocity);
        if (!getTileCollision() && abs(round(degrees(current_heading)) - round(degrees(velocity.heading()))) != 180) {
          current_heading = velocity.heading();
          break;
        } else {
          location.sub(velocity);
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    desired_heading = -1;
    current_heading = -1;
  }
}
```

So what my terrible code hopes to accomplish is the the enemy first tries to move directly at the player. If it encounters an obstacle, it will round its angle to the nearest 90 degrees, set desired_heading to this and try to move through. If it cant, it will rotate another 90 degrees and so forth, always keeping the original rounded angle in mind.

This doesn't work remotely well as first of all, rotating 90 degrees has a 50% chance to go in the exact wrong diretion, so I tried adding

```
if (abs(original_heading - velocity.heading()+turn) < abs(original_heading - velocity.heading()-turn)) {
    turn = radians(-90);
}
```

right before the `while (true)` but that broke the algorithm completely (sometimes the enemy will freeze in deep thought and not move ever again).

What am I doing terribly wrong? Should I try a different algorithm or does this one have potential?

I hope this is a better question now...

Comment: Maybe you could go towards destination and if your object hit something, make it turn around the obstacle (always in the same direction, maybe picking the best one 1st, keeping in mind what the original destination was). So you will need a collision detection and some algo. to go around obstacles. But because the world is generated, your optimal path will always be a "local one"

Comment: It's impossible to close this as a duplicate because it's unclear what you are asking/too broad because you're basically presenting a laundry list of requirements and very vague details about what you have tried.

Comment: @RC. I tried doing something of the sort, but the issue is picking the direction to go around the obstacle in the first place. Also, another obstacle might get in the way of circumventing the first obstacle... Though I must say, that solution is much better than the ones a tried. Thank you!

Comment: I find your question interesting, but you should really add some details, maybe a maze screenshot, maybe some code, probably both. Do you know [Dijkstra's_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)? It's for graphs, but I don't think it'd hard to adapt it for your maze. It's complexity is nearly linear with the size, so I don't think that pixeling the tiles should pose a problem.

Comment: Much better now, I hope, it gets reopened soon. Are you looking for a (close to) optimal path or does some directed rambling suffice (I guess your algorithm can get easily stuck in a corral)? +++ I guess, you're spending most time in `getTileCollision()`, which can most probably be optimized (precomputation, quad tree, or whatever).

Comment: This question would likely get better help on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @maaartinus Sorry, what do you mean by a corral? (I get a pen for livestock when I search the word on google). Also, any code or pseudo-code would be welcome, I'm just trying to figure out what is wrong with my current solution.

About `getTileCollision()` - it probably could be optimized very heavily, but that is a different topic altogether as the collision box for the enemy class can be a rectangle, circle, or polygon - it depends on the specific instance...

Comment: @Muhd Most of the questions regarding my project would certainly fit better in gamedev, but this specific problem (I think) is not specifically game-related, but AI-related, so I thought posting it here would be the better choice.

Comment: That's what I meant (I also used Google :D): Your tiles nearly completely enclose a rectangle leaving [just a single way out](http://www.wwmanufacturing.com/images/portfolio/maternity%20pen.jpg). So when you start in the desired direction, then you most probably hit a wall. +++ Sure, optimizing `getTileCollision` may be worth another question, but it's pretty important not to check all tiles every time. You could approximately measure how long it takes by executing it twice with something like `boolean getTileCollision() {return getTileCollisionOrg() && getTileCollisionOrg();}`

Comment: @maaartinus I have the enemy to only check tiles in its immediate vicinity. The tiles are stored as an ArrayList<Tile>, but instead of iterating over the entire arraylist (which has hundreds of millions of entries) locations of the tiles in the arraylist are stored in a JSONObject, which has entires of the sort: `str(tile_x) + " " + str(tile_y) : tile_index`, so all I have to do is check which tiles are in the enemy's immediate vicinity and then check for collisions with <5 tiles. Rather proud of that little bit of code :D

Comment: I'm afraid, that the idea is good, but the realization is not as string operations are dead slow (when compared to simple math). JSONObject sounds strange, a `HashMap` or `TreeMap` is what I'd use for this. +++ Have a look at [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree#Some_common_uses_of_quadtrees).